# How to control the transmission speed under libuv?

Tags: libuv

As we all know, libuv is an asynchronous network library, it will do its best to send out the data, however, in some cases, we can not take all the bandwidth, transmission speed needs to be controlled at the specified value, how to do this with libuv api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

libuv does not provide a built-in mechanism to do this, but it does give you enough information to build it. Assuming you're using TCP, you'd be calling `uv_write` repeatedly. You can then query the `write_queue_size` (http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/stream.html#c.uv_stream_t.write_queue_size) and stop waiting until it has drained a bit. You can do this check in the callback passes to `uv_write`.