# How to limit the bandwidth when read data under libuv

Tags: limit, bandwidth, libuv

As we all know, libuv is an asynchronous network library.
Now I code a **http download client with libuv**, but I don't know how to limit the speed during downloading. in other words, how to control the IO bandwidth when read data under libuv or asynchronous network library?

Similar questions:
1.[How to control the transmission speed under libuv?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38136581/how-to-control-the-transmission-speed-under-libuv)
2.[Rate-limiting plan in libuv #738](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/738)

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a throtteling proxy, here's how I did it:

I'll assume a maximum bandwith of 100kbps with a timeout of 10ms in this example and leave error handling up to you.

- call `read_start` for your incoming stream
- in the callback immediately call `read_stop`
- calculate the chunk size based on your max bps and a timeout (0.01s * maxBps = 1kB)
- store the chunked data in some kind of collection
- start a timer with our 10ms timeout
- in your timer callback:

  - check if there are chunks remaining
  - write a chunk of your data to your output stream
  - restart the timer if there are more chunks remaining
  - otherwise call `read_start` again for your input stream
- repeat.

I did this in Lua using luvit which is a wrapper for libuv (+ much much more) but you should be able to translate the intresting part easily.

Here's the releavant part of Lua code for reference. Note that I start my timer in the write callback here but that shouldn't make much of a difference. `send_data_to_upstream` is the incoming stream read callback.

```lua
local send_next_chunk
local send_data_to_upstream

send_data_to_upstream = function(err, data)
    if err then debug_print("Client error:" .. err) end
    if data then
        -- throttle reads
        self.sock.tcp_client:read_stop()

        -- chunkify the data
        self.chunks = splitByChunk(data, self:_get_chunk_size())
        debug_print("[DOWN]", "Client request: " .. #data)
        send_next_chunk()
    else
        -- Client disconnected, cleanup handles
        self:disconnect()
        debug_print("Client disconnected")
    end
end

send_next_chunk = function()
    if #self.chunks > 0 then
        debug_print("[DOWN]", "Chunks remaining: ", #self.chunks,
                    "next in:", self.throttle.delay)
        timer.setTimeout(self.throttle.delay, function()
            -- throttle transfer for consecutive chunks
            self.throttle.delay = self.throttle.timeout_ms

            -- send next chunk
            local head = table.remove(self.chunks, 1)
            self.sock.tcp_upstream:write(head, send_next_chunk)
            collectgarbage("step")
        end)
    else
        -- restart the client data pump
        self.throttle.delay = 0
        debug_print("[DOWN]", "Client request completed")
        self.sock.tcp_client:read_start(send_data_to_upstream)
    end
end
```